# How do I nest one layout within another in Ror?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, layout, render

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I’m a little confused about layouts.  I have an application layout, that I would like to apply to all pages.  I also have a

```
app/views/layouts/my_object.html.erb
```

that I would like to only apply to methods in my app/controllers/my_objects_controller.rb file, the top of which I have

```
class MyObjectsController < ApplicationController
  layout 'my_object'
```

The problem is that when my view is rendered, the code from the “my_object” layout is rendered but not the application layout code.  The my_object layout looks like the following

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "my_objects", :media => "all" %>

<%= render 'tabs' %>

<%= yield %>
```

How do I get both my application and my_object layout to render?

Answer (score 0):

Because the way you wrote it is just the way to override the application layout.

Make your object a partial. This is the way to do it. If you are attaching specific CSS to the partial do not forget to add it to your application.css file in order to have it loaded.

=== added
This will be in the view of your MyObject Controller class.

```
<%= render 'myobject', layout: "my_objects", , object: @object %>
```

Comment: I'm still not getting what you're explaning.  Make what object a partial?  What am I adding to my application.css file?  If you could include a code sample that woudl be the best.

Comment: you can pass the object to the partial as you would do for any view. Then call the partial in your view.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials